# Multiple conditions are not working in while loop in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to do multi condition check i.e., the input should not be empty and it should contain only numbers in while loop in Shell Script but i am facing multiple errors while trying to perform this operation. I have tried multiple options and i see multiple questions on this posted in Unix Stackexchange and Stack overflow but none of them helping that's why i am posting this question here
Option 1:

```
while [ \( -z "$account_number" \) && \( "$account_number" =~ "^[0-9]+$" \) ];
do      printf 'Input account Number RWDEx: '
        read -r account_number
        [ -z "$account_number" ]  && echo 'Account Number cannot be empty; try again.'
done
```

This is throwing error [: missing `]' many suggested this error because of the space issue between condition and brackets but it didn't work

Option 2:

```
while [[ -z "$account_number" && "$account_number" =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]
do      printf 'Input account Number RWDEx: '
        read -r account_number
        [ -z "$account_number" ]  && echo 'Account Number cannot be empty; try again.'
done
```

If i giving condition as above it not even asking for the input

Please help in solving this issue and i am using #!/bin/bash i tried even changing the script to /bin/bash instead of #!/bin/bash

Comment: There's no way `$account_number` can be both empty (`-z`) **and** (`&&`) match `^[0-9]+$`. Your logic is flawed. Note that only the `[` builtin of `yash` and `zsh` support  a `=~` operator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the reply can you help me how can i re frame this logic

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
#! /bin/bash -
n=
pattern='^(0+|[123456789][0123456789]*)$' # decimal integer number,
                                          # exclude 0123 octals
until [[ $n =~ $pattern ]]; do
  IFS= read -rp 'Enter a decimal number: ' n || exit # exit upon EOF
done
```

Or:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pattern='^(0+|[123456789][0123456789]*)$' # decimal integer number,
                                          # exclude 0123 octals
while true; do
  IFS= read -rp 'Enter a decimal number: ' n || exit # exit upon EOF
  if [ -z "$n" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Cannot be empty, try again"
  elif [[ ! $n =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo >&2 "Not a decimal integer number, try again"
  else
    break
  fi  
done
```

Or better, use the standard `sh` syntax, and then you don't even need `bash`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
while true; do
  printf >&2 'Enter a number: '
  IFS= read -r n || exit # exit upon EOF
  case $n in
    ("")
      echo >&2 "Cannot be empty, try again";;
    (*[!0123456789]* | 0*[!0]*)
      echo >&2 "Not a decimal integer number, try again";;
    (*)
      break;; # OK
  esac
done
```

Note that `[` is a shell builtin. The `[` of `bash` contrary to `zsh` or `yash` doesn't support a `=~` operator.

Also, if you do `[ x && y ]`, that's parsed as `cmd1 arg && cmd2 arg2`, so just runs `[ x` and if it's successful, run `y ]`.

`[[ ... ]]` on the other hand is a special shell construct (from ksh) inside which `&&` is also a form of *and* operator.

However, if you write:

```
[[ -z $var && $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

That's testing whether `$var` is both empty (`-z`) and matches `^[0-9]+$` which is not possible.

I think you meant:

```
[[ -z $var || ! $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
```

But even then the `-z $var` is redundant since if `$var` matches `^[0-9]+$` (one or more characters in the 0-9 range), it can't be empty.

Note that what `[0-9]` matches is more or less random in most locales on most systems, use `[0123456789]` if you want to match any decimal digits.

In shells like `bash`, it's generally a good idea to exclude numbers with leading zeros as they tend to be interpreted as octal numbers (where 010 means 8 for instance).

It's customary to issue user prompts on stderr (like `bash`'s `read -p` does) as they are not part of the normal output of the command (the output your script *produces* if any and which you may for instance want to pipe to some other command).